# Error when calling file in same directory using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Update: I was able to find the error in my code. The problem was that I didn't close my opening parenthesis with closing ones in my `console.log` for my `notes.js`.

I started a course on `node.js` and I am learning how to call other functions created from files on my local system. I have the directory `node-notes` in which I have two `javascript` files, `app.js` and `notes.js`. I am calling my `notes.js` in my `app.js`. I made a simple `console.log()` call just to make sure its working right in my `notes.js`. But when I try to run my code using the command `node app.js` I am getting the error below.[image]

Update: I am using Node 10.0.0

I have no idea what this means so can someone please explain what the error is and how I can fix it. Below I will post both codes for my `app.js` and `notes.js`

`app.js`

```
console.log("STARTING app.js")



// calling modules using require
// calling functions in fs module and putting in the 
// variable fs

const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const notes = require('./notes.js');


var user = os.userInfo();
console.log(user);


fs.appendFile('greetings.txt', 'Hello World!' + user.username , function(err){

if(err){
    console.log("There was an error")
}else{
    console.log("It was successful")
}

});
```

`notes.js`

```
console.log("Calling notes.js")
```

Comment: looks like you had a typo in your code that isn't replicated here.

Comment: and by that you mean i left out some of the code because i copied all of it.

Answer (score 3):

In *notes.js* you are missing a `"` to end the string.

`console.log("Calling notes.js)` should be `console.log("Calling notes.js")`

Thus you get a `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`